# What's the meaning of ?= right after ^?

Tags: c#, regex

Following is one of strong password validation that at least six characters and contains a digit, symbol, or punctuation mark.

```
(?x)^(?=.* ( \d | \p{P} | \p{S} )).{6,}
```

What's the meaning of `(?=.*` after `(?x)^`?

I understand `?=`expr is Lookahead that checks whether the text that follows matches expr. But in this case, only `^` that is start of a string is ahead.

Comment: I think we may have different understanding of the word "ahead" here - at that point, `^` has been matched, so it's *behind*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In words:

The comments flag is set (`(?x)`).

The start of the string (`^`) must be first, which must be followed by (`?=`) zero or more characters (`.*`), then either (`(||)`) a digit (`\d`), a punctuation mark (`\p{P}`) or a symbol (`\p{S}`).

After the start of string, there must be 6 or more of any characters (`.{6,}`)

Does that explain it?

Comment: @Grhm Yeah, thanks. Corrected. I know, I just seem to keep typing that wrong.